# OnItemSelectedListener called on screen rotation

Tags: android, spinner, screen-orientation

When I change the orientation of my screen in Android, an OnItemSelectedListener from a Spinner is called.

It's not just the emulator, it also happens on a physical phone.

How can I stop this from occurring?

Cheers.

Comment: The activity is recreated when you rotate the device. You need to handle this, not to stop occurring. Read Activity lifecycle chapter from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spinners are always selected. Your `OnItemSelectedListener` will be called when there is any change in the state of the `Spinner`, including when the `Spinner` is first set up. A normal orientation change will result in your activity being destroyed and recreated. So, if your `OnItemSelectedListener` is being called when your activity is first appearing on the screen, it will be called again when the orientation is changed.

> How can I stop this from occurring?

You might be able to play around with the timing of when you call `setOnItemSelectedListener()` compared to `setAdapter()`, to see if it helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, that makes sense. How can I play around with the timings? I am vet new to Android so please use simple words ;)

Comment: @Entropy1024: Change the order of the Java statements.

Answer (score 5):

You will also get a second call if the spinner's selectedItemPosition is not zero when the screen is rotated, as Android sets the position to what it was before rotation. Use onSaveInstanceState to count the number of spinners in a none zero position and use this count so that the OnItemSelected code just returns until the count has been decremented to zero.

You also need to be extremely careful with spinners that can have a visibility of View.GONE. I'll add some more text here when I can find the time to describe exactly how to handle these.

Comment: Could you please write why you should be careful with spinners that can have a visibility of View.GONE. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `OnItemSelectedListener` is called before the spinner contains its adapter so you need validate that the view is not null inside `OnItemSelected` method, like that:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if(view != null) { // <- here is the validation
      // Your code to do something with the selected item
    }
  }
  @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to help when it comes to rotation events.